# Windows: Upgraded from Win7 Win10 Enterprise for free. Now need to reinstall windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, bios, windows-update, product-key

I bought my machine from my employer with WIndows 7 installed (enterprise i believe it was). Microsoft then offered a free upgrade to Windows 10 for free and that offer lasted for a certain time period. The upgrade itself was permanent. I did the upgrade and as the installation was free I didn't have a product key to provide as such. Now my windows decided to do a Windows Update and the next time I started it up I got the error: "No bootable devices found". I went to bios settings, did a health test, came up 100% healthy. Opened the machine and re-connected the cables and everything. Tried to start it up. Didn't work. Went back into bios to change to legacy boot, dragged the os drive to the top of the list. Didn't work. I then created a bootable usb. That too didnt work. I then decided to take the machine to a professional. They called me a few days after dropoff and said I might have to buy a windows 10 to get it installed on there. I debated with them for a bit and they said they could try to install the windows 7 that the machine came with and hopefully that can get activated automatically. I then asked why it is impossible to install an un-activated version of Win 10 and then calling up microsoft to verify that I did indeed have an activated Win 10 version on the machine and therefore get my/an activation key? The guy argued his way out of that one pretty much saying that was not possible.

My question therefore is, is it not possible to get Win 10 installed in the machine without purchase, and then I can do the activation myself, whether by calling up microsoft to re-activate it for me, or by buying a new product key?

Comment: Not certain, so not posting as an answer. I *think* the issue might be that it's Enterprise. You can certainly install a fresh, nuke & pave, Win10 Home or Pro without a license key, then sort it out later, either by automatic activation or ring/buy from Microsoft.

Comment: just [reinstall Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1187569/174557) from lastest [Windows 10 ISO](https://superuser.com/a/1108086/174557) (create a bootable USB thumb drive from the ISO). During the free upgrade the hash of your PC was stored on Microsoft activation servers and during reinstall Windows 10 activates again. I did this several time and it works fine.

Comment: @Moab the title clearly says Enterprise. Unless you mean something else.

Comment: If the downvote could be please be explained, that would be great.

Comment: Enterprise never got free upgrade only Home and Pro system. I've already answered our question.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Must have been pro then. Certainly wasn’t home

Comment: ok, so get the ISO, reinstall Pro and you're fine.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get the product key as soon as possible, the nirsoft tool http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html always worked well for me, didn't try it with an external disk, but it seems to work, according to https://www.howtogeek.com/64600/how-to-recover-windows-and-software-keys-from-a-broken-computer/

Comment: I don't think the OP asks for a product key.  In case of "tl;dr", it's the last paragraph.

Comment: Seems the solution to his problem to me. Extract the product key, use it to install windows, perform the re-activation if necessary. I migrated a Win7 to Win10 and then from a physical machine to a VM following these steps.